# i can't use 'time' word in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't use 'time' word as my column name in mysql query.
This is my query code:(Not Working)

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger =  '-1' TIME =  '123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
```

Error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>   near 'time='123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'' at line 1

But this code is working:

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger =  '-1' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
```

Will I have to change my column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You're missing coma (,) after `deger =  '-1'`

2) You may enclose TIME into backticks (`) to prevent other possible errors

Correct (try it?) query spelling:

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger =  '-1', `TIME` =  '123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
```

**UPDATE**

Responding to comment:

correct query for decreasing `deger` column by 1 will be:

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger =  deger-1, `TIME` =  '123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
```

If you just need to set it to -1 then do:

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger = -1, `TIME` =  '123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
```

Also please note that syntax with single quotes (') should be used only with strings (varachar(...) columns etc.); for numbers that is incorrect. If you need to specify the number - just do it without any quotes. I've changed this for `deger` column (apparently it's numeric if you want to subtract something from it) but not for the others because I don't know their types. If columns `TIME`, `ip` and `premium` are also numbers then you'll need to also remove quotes from their values.

Comment: very thanks.. and i want to change deger column as -1 but this code does operation. if deger column is 1, this query change as 0?

Comment: No. The query you have will change the column `deger` to strict -1. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the keyword "time" by using backticks:

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger =  '-1', `TIME` =  '123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
```

I believe you also dropped a comma, which may be the cause of the error you are getting here. But in general, if you have a column name which is special to MySQL, escape it.

Comment: very thanks.. and i want to change deger column as -1 but this code does operation. if deger column is 1, this query change as 0?

Comment: @Joseph: try `SET deger=-1`, since what you've got will set it to a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you must enclose the name in backticks `` ` ``. As a general rules I *always* enclose column names in them, as it makes it clear what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma before `TIME`:

```
UPDATE ip_p SET deger =  '-1', TIME =  '123' WHERE ip =  '12' AND premium =  '1'
                             ^
```